# How do canyons form?

Tags: erosion, simulation, landscape

I read that canyons are the result of long-time erosion from a plateau but is there any simulation I could play with to understand the phenomenon better?

Comment: Get some sand, spread it as a 5 cm thick layer for about a square meter. It doesn't have to be totally flat, but rather even, and there should be a gentle slope. Now get some water and gently pour it on the elevated side of your square. The water will run downhill, and in the process wash away/erode the sand, carving tiny canyons. Tada, your own simulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are talking about subaerial (as opposed to submarine) canyons, and are mostly thinking of numerical (as opposed to physical) models.

I expect there are numerical models suitable for submarine application, but I haven't looked for them. There are physical models of rivers too, but I think they are better suited to modeling 'soft' sedimentary systems like deltas, floodplains, etc.

Here are some examples of numerical models in Python, starting with the research-grade ones (but if it was me I'd probably start with the ones I've thrown at the end):

##### PyBadlands

[image: Sketch of Badlands models]

> an open-source python-based framework that allows for evaluation of sediment transport, landscape dynamics and sedimentary basins evolution under the influence of climate, sea waves and tectonics

[Read the paper.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5896951/) [Get the code.](https://github.com/badlands-model/badlands)

##### Landlab

This is a high-level toolkit for building models, but their docs point to all sorts of examples, several of which have to do with landscape evolution. For example, see Terrainbento and SPACE, below.

[Check out the website.](http://landlab.github.io/#/) [Read a nice poster.](https://landlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/a4993af91f623377252d7bdb27fae60f/EGU_poster_2016.pdf)[Get the code.](https://github.com/landlab/landlab)

##### Terrainbento

This package builds on Landlab (above) to compare a large number of different Earth surface modelling strategies.

[Read the paper.](https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/12/1267/2019/) [Get the code.](https://github.com/TerrainBento/terrainbento)

##### SPACE

Another package that builds on Landlab, this time to study the simultaneous modeling of alluvial and bedrock erosion and transport.

[Read the paper.](https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/10/4577/2017/) [Get the code.](https://github.com/cmshobe/pub_shobe_etal_GMD)

##### Some others I've come across:

- An interactive model: https://github.com/fastscape-lem/ipyfastscape
- A simple model: https://github.com/johnjarmitage/flem
- A simple model, from scratch: https://github.com/mtb-za/landscape_evolution_short_course/blob/master/notebooks/FastScape.ipynb
- A global model (!): https://github.com/Geodels/gospl

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a model you can play with, but there are some very interesting videos of models here:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=landscape+erosion+model